# Cryptography options

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, encryption

My ASP.NET MVC 4 website (hosted as an Azure web role) stores some sensitive data in a SQL Server table.  When a user begins the workflow that generates the data, I get a random key from the Rijndael implementation and store it in the session state. I use that key for round trip encryption/decryption to and from the database throughout the life of the session.  Thus, only code running in that session (or, at least, code that has access to the key stored in the session state) can decrypt the data.

Now I have a need to allow the database records to hang around for a while and to access them from a different session. Since this session doesn't have access to the key stored in the previous session's state, it seems to me that my best, easiest course of action is probably to encrypt all of the data using a key that is baked into my application code.

I should add that I'm trying hard to NOT use any Azure hooks so that my website can be hosted on any ASP.NET host.

I have two questions:

1. Is my existing scheme (storing my key in session state) secure on Azure if my session state scheme is `<sessionState mode="StateServer" />` and I am, in fact, using multiple hosts? (Please be kind... I'm still figuring out this whole ASP.NET/Azure thing. At the moment I'm using InProc session state; I haven't even tried to get the multiple host thing working yet.)
2. Using a random per-session key seems to be a stronger encryption scheme than using a single baked-in key. But, on the other hand, the whole SSL world is predicated on having all communications protected by a single private key baked into an SSL certificate. Should I be concerned about using a key baked into my code? Is there a better scheme - something akin to what I was doing using per-session keys?

Comment: SSL generates a new secret key each time a connection is setup, the public key is only used to encrypt the secret key so it can be sent to the server known as a key-exchange.

Comment: @Despertar: But if your SSL private key is stolen then the encrypted key exchange can be snooped and the whole scheme breaks down.  My point was that this is an example of a widely used scheme that relies on one secret stored in a (hopefully) hard-to-access container.

Comment: SSL provides optional ephemeral diffie-hellman (EDH) ciphersuites that provide forward secrecy. In these ciphersuites the long-term public key (e.g. the RSA key or ECDSA key) is only used for authenticating the exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1.**

[Securing Session State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178201.aspx). It doesn't tell you what it's doing unfortunately, but does tell you a lot of things not to do, which should make you appropriately paranoid.

**2.**

Securing data at rest is a really difficult problem, you are going to have to store a key, you just have to keep it as secure and separate from your data as possible. If you need to segment your data, you can have key per x (per user, whatever) that are encrypted with a master key.  The ability to rotate keys is really helpful maintaining security, so you can swap out keys overtime without consequence. The [keyczar](http://www.keyczar.org/) framework, which I [ported to c#](http://jbtule.github.com/keyczar-dotnet/) has a simple design for key rotation.